# c# sqlite encoding utf8

Tags: c#, sqlite, encoding, utf-8

I have very strange problem (I have searched - this is a common problem, but I don't find any working solution).

I'm using C# (.net 4.0) and SQLite.
Pragma encoding shows me UTF8, so I want to save data in this encoding. 
I tried to use somelike this:

```
     private String ToUTF8(string input) {

        Encoding ecdng = Encoding.Default;

        byte[] bts = ecdng.GetBytes(input);
        ecdng = Encoding.UTF8;
        return ecdng.GetString(bts, 0, bts.Length);
        //return input;
    }

    private String FromUTF8(string input)
    {

        Encoding ecdng = Encoding.UTF8;

        byte[] bts = ecdng.GetBytes(input);
        ecdng = Encoding.Default;
        return ecdng.GetString(bts, 0, bts.Length);
        //return input;
    }
```

but it doesn't work. I use ToUTF8 when I'm going to save data and FromUTF8 when I selecting data.

Second solution which I found is:

```
        private IDbDataParameter AddParameter(IDbCommand command, string paramName, DbType type, object value)
    {
        IDbDataParameter parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = paramName;
        parameter.DbType = type;
        if (value != null)
            parameter.Value = value;
        else
            parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        return parameter;
    }
```

but it doesn't work too.

I want to store in my database polish words. When I preview data via SQLiteStudio I have strange symbols in place of polish letters. 
In program I have the same problem, but other symbols on polish letters.

Can anyone help me with this?

Best Regards, 
Matt.

Comment: The database driver automatically converts between UTF-8 and the encoding that C#'s `String` uses. You do not need to do anything in your code.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response, but without any conversion on c# it still doesn't work. I database I have ? on place, where should be polish letter..

Comment: Hmm, maybe I have problem when I reading data from file? When I print file content I don't have polish letters too. I read it with read System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file, Encoding.UTF8);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I read data from file - using ReadAllLines with encoding UTF8, when I change to default i have polish letters :)